# By RAW, can you use your free object interaction while taking the "Use an Object" action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, objects

There is a drinking contest between a Dwarf and a Halfling to see who can drink flagons of ale the fastest. Normally one would assume the Dwarf would have an advantage at drinking, but unbeknown to them the Halfling is a Thief.

From the rules for [Interacting With Objects Around You](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#InteractingwithObjectsAroundYou)

> Here are a few examples of the sorts of thing you can do in tandem with your movement and action:
>
> - drink all the ale in a flagon

From the rules for the [Use an Object](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UseanObject) action:

> You normally interact with an object while doing something else, such as when you draw a sword as part of an attack. When an object requires your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action. *This action is also useful when you want to interact with more than one object on your turn.*

**Can someone taking the Use an Object action to drink 2 flagons of ale in a single action?**

Can a Thief take Use an Object, then use Fast Hands to Use an Object again, then move 0ft, drinking 5 flagons of ale in a single turn?

In the quote above I have italicised a sentence, does this limit you to 1 object interaction per turn for free, or is this an explanation why someone would ever use this when they can interact with objects for free?

Note: I know that using action surge you could drink even more flagons of ale in a turn, this isn't an optimisation question, the ale drinking is just an example. If you want to present a more powerful drinking champion then go ahead, *after* the question is answered :)

Also note: **I am interested in the official rules. This means a RAW reading to the best of your ability**

If you want to provide some houserules about interacting with objects, please do so **after** first addressing RAW/RAI so as not to create partial answers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100098/discussion-on-question-by-jgn-by-raw-can-you-use-your-free-object-interaction-w).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The Rogue could drink 3 flagons

The section on "Other Activity On Your Turn" states:

> You can also interact with **one object or feature of the environment** for free, during either your move or your action.

It later presents a list of things you can do "*in tandem with your movement and action*". This limits your number of free object interactions to one per turn and *does not limit during which action you can take an object interaction*.

Thus the Rogue could spend an action to Use An Object (drink a flagon), drink a flagon as an object interaction at that time, and then use Fast Hands to take the Use An Object action again, drinking their third and final flagon.

---

Sidenote: The Fighter's Action Surge feature would allow them to drink one additional flagon by taking the Use An Object action; similarly the [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell would allow you to drink one additional flagon by taking the Use An Object action.

Comment: I have an entire group of players who are going to love this answer!  Thank you!